# why does the $p$th-power Frobenius morphism on an elliptic curve equal $\sqrt{-p}$?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, finite-fields, elliptic-curves

Let $E$ be an elliptic curve over $\mathbb{F}_p$, then the $p$th-power Frobenius morphism, denoted $\pi: (x,y) \mapsto (x^p, y^p)$, is an endomorphism on $E$.

There is an argument showing that if $E$ is supersingular, then $\text{End}_{\mathbb{F}_p}E$ is an order in the imagimary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-p})$, containing $\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{-p})$. I don't know why $\sqrt{-p}$, regarded as an endomorphism on $E$, equals $\pi$ which means $\pi^2+[p]=0$.

As I know of, if $E$ is supersingular then $[p]=\hat{\pi}\circ\pi$ is purely inseparable and we must have $\pi=\hat{\pi}$, i.e., $\pi^2=[p]$.

Comment: It is $[p]=-\pi^2$.

Comment: @reuns I know that any isogeny can be decomposed into a separable isogeny and a power of $\pi$. So either $[p]=[-1]\pi^2$ or $[p]=\pi^2$ in this case. I was looking at Remark 7.7 in this lecture notes from MIT:https://dspace.mit.edu/bitstream/handle/1721.1/111949/18-783-spring-2015/contents/lecture-notes/MIT18_783S15_lec7.pdf
and just thought  $[p]=\pi^2$. Maybe it's a typo.  How do you verify that though?

Comment: I'd say the main point is your lemma 7.14 which forbids $[p]=\pi^2$ as it would give that $\pi+1$ is self-dual

Comment: @reuns sorry, what would go wrong if $\pi+1$ is self-dual? Not sure if this is relevant, but assuming that I see $(\pi+1)^2=[p+1]+2\pi$ is separable since $p \nmid p+1$.

Comment: I thought if $ E/k $ is supersingular, $ End_k(E) $ is a quaternion algebra, in particular, not an order in an imaginary quadratic field..

Comment: @CraniumClamp It depends on the trace $t$ of $q$th-power Frobenius morphism $\pi$.  If $E$ is supersingular over $K=\mathbb{F}_q$, then $\text{End}_{\overline{K}} E$ is an order in a quaternion algebra, but in general not every endomorphism is defined over $K$, i.e., $\text{End}_{K} E \subsetneq \text{End}_{\overline{K}}E$.  If  $t=\pm 2\sqrt{q}$, then $\text{End}_{K} E = \text{End}_{\overline{K}}E$, but otherwise $\text{End}_{K}E$ is an order in an imaginary quadratic field $\mathbb{Q}(\pi)$. See Chapter 4 of William C. Waterhouse. Abelian varieties over finite fields.

Comment: @Andy, you're right, I'm used to working over algebraically closed fields. Thanks for correcting me.

Comment: @reuns Alright, my comment to Cranium reminded me that $q$th-power Frobenius map satisfies $\pi^2-t \pi +q=0$ and if $E$ is defined over $\mathbb{F}_p$ the trace of $p$th-power Frobenius map is $0$. Please let me know if there is other way to see this.

Comment: $(\sqrt{p}+1)^2$ is not an integer so if $\pi^2=p$ then $\pi+1$ is not self-dual. Check Silverman's AEC how he proves this.

Comment: @reuns thanks, there is an exercise in chapter 5 of AEC, which explicitly compute rational maps defining $[p]$.